# Upgrading to new asynchrous Google Analytics code - should you do it?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I had read somewhere and have now forgotten that upgrading to the new asynchronous code will not enable one to track actual clicks for downloading items when user stays on the same page and that for tracking that you need to use the old version of GA code.

My question is, is that still the case and does anyone have any other reasons for not upgrading to use the newer asynchronous tracking?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...are you sure the "old" version of GA automatically tracked downloads?  AFAIK GA never automatically tracked download links, that you always had to attach GA code (like a `_trackEvent` call) to your links yourself.  But in any case, it's pretty easy to do it yourself, so it's really not a big deal.  Plus, you get lots of benefits  upgrading, and one day it may not even be an option to stick with the old version...

If you have jQuery you can for example do this:

```
// file types you want to consider a download
var downloadFileTypes = ['pdf','doc','docx','mp4']; 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').filter(function() {
    var ext = $(this).attr('href').split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    return ( $.inArray(ext, downloadFileTypes )>-1 );
    })
    .click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', $(this).attr('href')]);
  });
});
```

If you do not have a framework like jQuery, you can still do this easy enough with `.getElementsByTagName()` and using regular loops and conditions instead of the jQuery conveniences like `.filter` and `.inArray`

edit: Some things to note about that example:

- the jQuery code was an example to hook the GA code to standard links pointing to the file types you specify in `downloadFiletypes`.  It will only apply to links that exist at the time the code is executed.  If you have links that may be dynamically generated on the page later, consider looking into `.on()` instead of `.click()`
- you will need to make tweaks to matching links you want to consider downloads if they do not point to regular files with extensions.  For instance, some websites have a controller script that expects a parameter with an ID and it dynamically serves up a pdf or whatever..if your files are like this, you will have to alter the logic to look for that instead.